# owl-carousel-autoWidth, Avoid blank space in visible area when last item visible

Tags: jquery, html, slider, carousel

**my code**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin:10,
    loop:false,
    autoWidth:true,
    nav:true,
    items:1,
})
```

**note:** 1) **loop** false (I dont need loop items )

2) **items** - I dont know how to manage show items number ( carousel implementing on fluid responsive website  )

**my target** Next button should hide when last item visible (I need items always fit in the visible area)

[myfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/on5qsyvz/1/)

Comment: it looks like the plugin doesn't support this functionality, but you can always bind an event to next link and hide it when the last slide is shown.

Comment: @CerlinBoss Please help me any example code ?

Answer (score 4):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/on5qsyvz/5/)

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin:10,
    loop:false,
    autoWidth:true,
    nav:true,
    items:1,
    onInitialized : function(){
        if($('.owl-item').first().hasClass('active'))
            $('.owl-prev').hide();
        else
            $('.owl-prev').show();
        }
    })
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel',function(e){
    if(e.item.index == 0)
        $('.owl-prev').hide();
    else
        $('.owl-prev').show();
    if(e.page.count == (e.page.index + 1))
        $('.owl-next').hide();
    else
        $('.owl-next').show();
})
```

I have attached two functions to two events (`onInitialized` and `changed.owl.carousel`).

the function inside `onInitialized` will hide the prev button `onload`(this can also be achieved by css.) the function inside `changed.owl.carousel` will hide/show both `prev` and `next` on respective conditions.

For more docs on event, refer [this](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html)

Comment: You are right but little problem , my Question is when last item came to visible area then do not work next button @Cerlin Boss

Comment: what?? can you reproduce that error in a fiddle? for me it was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, I worked this out by trial and error then win!

php:

```
<script>
    jQuery("#name-your-slider").owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        dots: false,
        autoWidth: true,
        mergeFit: true,
        center: true,
        margin: 5,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            768: {
                items: 2
            },
            1024: {
                // autoWidth: true,
                items: 3
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
```

scss:

```
#name-your-slider 
{
    .owl-stage
    {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;

        .owl-item
        {
            /* 775px is the flex basis because it is the widest slide size
               don't let it grow (there are no wider slides) do let it shrink
               because there are thinner slides */
            flex: 0 1 775px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

owl carousel 2.3.4 have not fixed this bug.

But this code can work.

Just Insert between line:1215 and line:1216 in owl.carousel.js-2.3.4

```
// Custom change : #1 Fixed the last item space to the right when set autoWith with true;
// Custom change : #1 Re-fixed last item space to right when all items width small than the container width;
// Custom change : #4 Fixed items scrolled left even when items width small than container width;
var settings = this.settings,
        iterator = this._items.length,
        itemsWidthSum = this._items[--iterator].width(),
        elementWidth = this.$element.width(),
        accommodate = true;

while (iterator--) {
    itemsWidthSum += this._items[iterator].width() + this.settings.margin;
    if (itemsWidthSum > elementWidth) {
        accommodate = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (accommodate)
{
    // Custom change : #4 Fixed if items width small than container width, reset coordinate with 0;
    coordinate = 0;
}
else
{
    // Custom change : #3 Fixed with the case of iterator(this._items.length) == 0;
    if ((settings.autoWidth || settings.merge)
            && !settings.loop
            && iterator > 0 && position > 0
            && position > iterator) {
        var tempPosition = position,
                reciprocalItemsWidth = 0;
        while (tempPosition < this._items.length) {
            reciprocalItemsWidth += this._items[tempPosition++].width() + this.settings.margin;
        }
        var direction = settings.rtl ? -1 : 1;
        coordinate = coordinate + direction * (elementWidth - reciprocalItemsWidth + this.settings.margin);
    }
}
```